# Call subclass's property in superclass?

Tags: ios, swift, subclass

I have a superclass and multiple child classes. I'd like to access a child classes' property in the parent class in some functions, so I don't have to have so much boilerplate code. The parent class is never instantiated directly.

Is this doable via parent/subclass pattern, or should I implement a delegate pattern?

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   var parentClassArray: [AnyObject]?

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
      let result: AnyObject = childClassArray![indexPath.row]   
      //is this somehow doable or can I only call parentClassArray?
   }
}

class ChildViewController: ParentViewController {
   var childClassArray: [Product]?
}
```

Update:

Here's my rationale for asking this question, hopefully it'll help.

I am currently using `parentClassArray: [AnyObject]?` in `ParentViewController` so I can support multiple classes in the array. The `ParentViewController` has methods which implement `UITableViewDelegate` that displays rows, handle selections, present segues, etc. based on the type of object in the array. I'd rather not reimplement (copy & paste) the same code in all subclasses of `ParentViewController`.

I actually got this concept to partially work, however, I'm getting random `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors and I'm trying to decipher whether it's my parent/subclass pattern or some other reason. I've been banging my head on this topic for over a week and am willing to try all variations now. Ugh!

Hence my question on using variables of subclass in parent class. I read you can override parent class variables using this code, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way.

```
var childClassArray: [User]?
override var parentClassArray: [AnyObject]? {
    get {
        return self.childClassArray
    }
    set {
        super.parentClassArray = self.childClassArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more what you want to do ultimately. As you mentioned "parent class is never instantiated directly", then i think you can override whatever you are trying to do in parent class, into the child class itself. That way you don't have to bother about accessing child property. Otherwise you can go for delegate pattern.

Comment: Thanks Gandalf, I'm relatively new to Swift/Objective C, so thanks for your help. I'll update the question with more detail.